# CodeIgniter Session Issues

Tags: codeigniter

I set session in a controller function like

```
$search = array(
    'search_count' => count($data['result']),
    'projectInfo' => $data['result']
    );

$this->session->set_userdata($search);
```

where $data['result'] is an array;

but if I try to access this variable in other function of same controller it shows nothing:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata('projectInfo'));
```

though on using `print_r($this->session->userdata('search_count'));` it shows correct value.

also if I use `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());` in second function of same controller it does not show array value index which I have already set in first function

```
 Array
(
    [session_id] => 4adf3a42ee64ffca2b2f273cb293a10a
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
    [last_activity] => 1347689522
    [user_data] => 
)
```

Comment: `print_r($data['result'])` and tell what it is displaying

Comment: it shows my fetched records from MySQL db tables

Comment: I can also catch $this->session->userdata('projectInfo'); array values in view file.

Comment: You can see it if you retrieve it properly...in view file you might have given objects to retrieve the db data;whereas in your controller, you aren't doing it. I think you are printing it directly.. it doesn't print anything like that. You must use objects

Comment: What is the purpose of calling it in another function? i mean what do you wnat there? Complete record or a particular file?

Comment: My search result based on some filter and I want to show all searched records one-by-one with Next link where Next link contain next coming record[saved in session] such that if the user click Next I catch session array Id for that particular record & show result without hit db again & again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16724/discussion-between-php-ferrari-and-bhuvan-rikka)

Comment: Is your session stored in the database, or in the cookie? Perhaps it is being truncated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I added Native PHP Session Class

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you can't save arrays into a session without [serializing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) them first.

```
$search = array(
    'search_count' => count($data['result']),
    'projectInfo' => $data['result']
    );

$this->session->set_userdata($search);
```

Becomes:

```
$search = array(
    'search_count' => count($data['result']),
    'projectInfo' => serialize($data['result'])
    );

$this->session->set_userdata($search);
```

Now if you want to retrieve the array:

```
$data = unserialize($this->session->userdata('projectInfo'));
print_r($data);
```

Please note that you should use the database to store sessions when you are setting large amounts of data in a session.

config.php

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
```